# How can ensure that my LAMP server isn't avilable for online access?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I'm currently using LAMP (MySQl + PhP + PhpMyAdmin) for web development class, but I'm kinda scared that someone could access to my data trough it.

How can i ensure that my server isn't available to the public? i want it only for me, i don't want to share it over the net or the Internet.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04.5

I'm using Apache 2.4, PHP5.

Answer (score 0):

Will you only be accessing it locally via the localhost address?

You could use iptables firewall to allow only outgoing connections from your computer (and incoming traffic related to that):

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

where eth0 would be your network interface (could be wlan0 in case you're using a wireless, check with ifconfig).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply deny except your local network and localhost

`sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

In there you need to add/change

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from YOUR_LOCAL_NETWORK 
  Allow from 127
</Directory>
```

YOUR_LOCAL_NETWORK could be 192.168.1.0/24

Everything else will be denied by default.

After you changed the file you need to restart apache

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Will it work if I do it in  etc/apache2/apache2 conf?  The path you specified you take me to a  blank file

Comment: Yes of course, that is the conf file, sorry. I changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate I will add those lines in the morning and I will come back as soon as I can to give you feedback about it

Comment: But it only restricts the access to your apache webserver not to your database. Maybe it would be better to use iptable to restrict the access to the whole system, as @mr_mezz pointed out!

Comment: But AFAIK mysql remote access is disabled by default, plus I don't know how to configure iptables

Comment: Okay. I hope it works as desired. BTW if you use a router it should not be a problem that someone is trying to access your webserver.